# WordPress plugins search error

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I am getting

> "An Unexpected HTTP Error occurred during the API request."

error when I search for plugin in the plugin installation page. Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the timeout limit?

WordPress sets a timeout limit for every request. If that treshold is crossed for your request, you will get this message.

To resolve this issue you can increase the time limit to a higher value. Go to the '`wp-includes`' folder of your WordPress installation and edit the `http.php` file.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Would you please mind accepting the answer and/or voting it up. :-)